# Integrating the cross product of a gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Is it possible to compute the integral,
$$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbf{r_1}(t)}^{\mathbf{r_1}(t)}\nabla(f)\times \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$
Without resorting to using parametric definitions and then integrating component-wise?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbf{r}_{1}\pars{t}}^{\mathbf{r}_{2}\pars{t}}
\nabla\mrm{f}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\times\dd\mathbf{r} & =
\int_{\mathbf{r}_{1}\pars{t}}^{\mathbf{r}_{2}\pars{t}}
\verts{\begin{array}{ccc}
\ds{\hat{x}} & \ds{\hat{y}} & \ds{\hat{z}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\mrm{f}_{x}\pars{\mathbf{r}}} & \ds{\mrm{f}_{y}\pars{\mathbf{r}}} & \ds{\mrm{f}_{z}\pars{\mathbf{r}}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\dd x} & \ds{\dd y} & \ds{\dd z}
\end{array}}
\\[5mm] & =
\hat{x}\int_{\mathbf{r}_{1}\pars{t}}^{\mathbf{r}_{2}\pars{t}}
\bracks{\mrm{f}_{y}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\,\dd z -
\mrm{f}_{z}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\,\dd y} +
\hat{y}\int_{\mathbf{r}_{1}\pars{t}}^{\mathbf{r}_{2}\pars{t}}
\bracks{\mrm{f}_{z}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\,\dd x -
\mrm{f}_{x}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\,\dd z}
\\[2mm] & +
\hat{z}\int_{\mathbf{r}_{1}\pars{t}}^{\mathbf{r}_{2}\pars{t}}
\bracks{\mrm{f}_{x}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\,\dd y -
\mrm{f}_{y}\pars{\mathbf{r}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}